# Get the file name without providing the filename in bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline script which generates an html with a random name. I need to get the file name. The file will be HTML file. I tried by giving like this -

```
 sh """FILE=`basename /customer/files/html-files/*.html`"""
 echo "${FILE}"
```

Is there any way i can just get the html file name alone. Please help

So if there is a file- sample.html in that loctaion. The echo output will be `sample`

Comment: what do you mean "html file name alone? Please provide expected result, because script above should already returns filename alone.

Comment: If I have a file - sample.html. The echo should print "sample" alone @Saboteur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basename has option for this:

```
sh """
FILE=`basename /customer/files/html-files/*.html .html`
echo ${FILE}
"""
```

Comment: It returned * . I think it considers * as a file name

Comment: maybe no html files found in the directory?

Comment: No...it has got files

Answer (score 2):

This works if you have just one file on that directory.

```
def filename = sh (script: 'basename customer/files/html-files/*html',returnStdout:true).trim()
def filenameWithoutExtension = filename.take(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
```